# 2011 Chevrolet equinox check engine light

Tags: chevrolet, catalytic-converter, equinox, engine-system-service-required

I got my 2011 Chevy Equinox back from the dealer for the engine repair on the oil consumption. This was covered by Chevy due to a class action lawsuit regarding this issue. Today, a week after getting my car back, the check engine light came on. I drove to the dealership for them to check code. They came back saying it was a generic code for catalytic converter which isnt covered, but they will check if its related. I believe it is very related. I've never had an issue with anything outside of oil consumption.  I'm looking for reliable information as to how the engine repair may have set off this code. I do not know the exact code.

Comment: Without knowing the specific code number that turned on the check engine light, we'd be guessing. You might stop by an auto parts store; many will connect a code reader that displays the code(s), and do so without charge.

Comment: If it was a direct result of the work that was performed it probably would have come on as you were leaving the lot. Sounds more like the change in engine performance has brought new problems to light that may have been squeaking by the system checks before

Comment: @narkeleptk - Not necessarily. Assuming they pulled the battery connection, which would have reset the computer (they might have had to directly reset the computer ... either way), the drive cycle for the vehicle may have not completed until a week after the service, depending on how the OP has driven the vehicle.

Comment: If it had oil consumption due to oil burning in the combustion chamber, it could have damaged the cat during that time. It just now failed due to the prior abuse. (Just a possibility).

Comment: Thanks all. I will stop by an auto store to get the exact code.  All answers seem possible.  The oil consumption was due to oil burning. They replaced valve pistons timing belt etc.  I was burning over a quart every 700 miles.